# Why is congruence modulo n defined for n > 1?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, definition, integers

Many literature gives the definition of congruence modulo n for n > 1.

Is there a serious reason to avoid n = 1?  Otherwise, do we get rid of the case just because the congruence modulo 1 is too trivial?

EDIT:
My apologies, "Many literature" would be wrong.  I've investigated several textbooks and found none of those restricts modulus as n > 1.  Only Wikipedia and articles that may refer to Wikipedia give the restriction.

In Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, the origin of the congruence relation, modulus are numbers with no restriction.  A few textbooks *remark* modulo 1 is trivial, and so we usually *assume* n > 1 in practice, but it is just an assumption and not a definition.

Comment: mod 1 for integers is trivial, but for reals is quite useful: it's the fractional part.

Comment: On integers, mod $0$ is equality and mod $1$ everything is congruent. Mod $-n$ is the same as mod $n$.

Comment: Though if you ask many programming languages, $\bmod 0$ is undefined and not identity: [Why is $n\bmod 0$ undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516251)

Comment: @peterwhy In Arturo's claim that "$\!\!\bmod 0\:\!$ is equality" he means they are the same *equivalence relation*, i.e. he refers to $\!\bmod\!$ as a relation, not an operator. But you refer to the binary operation $\!\bmod\!$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) explains how the two are related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is n mod 0 undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516251/why-is-n-mod-0-undefined)

Comment: **Note: the proposed dupe is wrong**. This question concerns $\!\bmod 1$ but the dupe concerns $\!\bmod 0,\,$ which are very different congruences. Please read more carefully when proposing dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is there no serious reason to avoid modulus $\,n = 1\,$ but it may prove cumbersome to do so. In many modular arguments it is natural to work modulo an unknown modulus $\,n,\,$ including the possibility $\,n = 1$.

For example, a nice technique to prove that $\,d = \gcd(a,b)= 1\,$ is to use *equational* reasoning $\!\bmod d\,$ to prove $\,a\equiv 0\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 0\Rightarrow |d| = 1.\,$ This allows us to replace less intuitive manipulation of *divisibility* statements by more intuitive manipulation of *equations (congruences)* - allowing us to employ equational logic familiar since grade school. For a simple example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4455471/242) posted a few days ago, which essentially exploits  *uniqueness of inverses* (to prove $r\equiv -b),\,$ an argument that would be a bit harder to *discover* while thinking in divisibilty language. Compare also the conciseness of that two-line proof to the other answers using alternative arguments (one of many examples  one could give illustrating the "cumbersome" claim above).

Comment: Please use due diligence in searching for dupes, before answering.

Comment: @amWhy The proposed dupe is incorrect. This question is about modulus $n = 1$ not $n = 0.\,$ If you are aware of a *correct* dupe then post it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The remainder of $m/1$ is 0, and the remainder of $n/1$ is also 0.  Since $0=0$, then $m ≡ n \pmod 1$ .  It's a perfectly cromulent operation, just not used much because it's trivial.

Though, as lhf pointed out in their comment, $\bmod 1$ is more interesting on $\mathbb{R}$ than on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: "mod" is not an operation here, it is a ternary relation.